# Post multiple urls in one post using iphone sharekit

Tags: iphone, ios, sharekit

I want to post text(on twitter, fb, mail) like following using share kit:

> Hi,
>
> This is share text
>
> Click here to do something *<=== this should be a link*
>
> Click here to another something *<=== this should be a link*
>
> Cheers

I have following code:

```
-(IBAction)shareOnTwitter:(id)sender
{
    [SHK setRootViewController:self];
    SHKItem *item;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://dosomething.com"];
    item = [SHKItem URL:url title:@"HI,\n\nThis is share text\n\nCheers"];
    [SHKTwitter shareItem:item];

}

- (IBAction)shareOnFacebook:(id)sender
{
    SHKItem *item;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://dosomething.com"];
    item = [SHKItem URL:url title:@"HI,\n\nThis is share text\n\nCheers"];
    [SHKFacebook shareItem:item];

}

- (IBAction)shareWithMail:(id)sender
{
    SHKItem *item;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://dosomething.com"];
    item = [SHKItem URL:url title:@"HI,\n\nThis is share text\n\nCheers"];
    [SHKMail shareItem:item];

}
```

But the url is appended at the end. How can I add multiple links with my text and bring the links in the middle.

Comment: Awwwwwwwwwwwwwww no answers yet................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to change the ShareKit classes that handle these services:

- SHKFacebook.m: the "-(BOOL)send" method.
- SHKTwitter.m: the "-(void)showTwitterForm" method.
- SHKMail.m: the "-(BOOL)sendMail" method.

It's easy for Twitter and Mail, you only have to create a NSString with the text of the message, like you want. With Facebook you have to change the attachment, you can see the facebook API [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/attachments/) for more options.

Answer (score 1):

I just looked in the documentation. ShareKit isn't designed to share long information. Only text, images, files or urls (and only one at a time). You will have to dig into programming them on your own (or find a better library).

- for mail you can read the documentation of [MFMailComposeViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html)
- for twitter and facebook you need something different, just watch for an web tutorial

Answer (score 1):

Basically you want to first create html formatted text with links inside, and then load it to text SHKItem and share that.

```
SHKItem *item = [SHKItem text:yourHTMLFormattedString];
[SHKMail shareItem:item];
```

It might need some customization, as each service might handle html formatted text differently. but at least mail sharer should have no problems.

URL SHKItem is for different purpose - solely for single URL sharing, and each sharer handles it differently, eg. Facebook automatically adds image from webpage, Twitter shortens it etc.

One more hint, just for case you are not aware - there is [ShareKit 2.0](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/) which has some new features, is updated and maintained.