# How to post href link to facebook wall in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, facebook-graph-api, ios7

I am posting a message on my facebook wall. I want to post a **href** link with my message. When I click on that link, it should take me to another facebook page. Please see the below screen shot. If it's possible please give your suggestions or code. Please help me.

[image]

Comment: r u tried with `share kit` framework need assistance try this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10124340/post-multiple-urls-in-one-post-using-iphone-sharekit)

Comment: no @Anbu.Karthik. how to implement that using Share kit framework. if you have any sample code?

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik can I implement this with out using Share kit framework.
is this implement using facebooksdk.framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assume that this is your `NSString` like

```
NSString *mesage =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"FINAL @[Page-id1] - 0 @ @[Page-id2]  via  ....",passyourPage-id1,passyourPage-id2];


NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                       mesage, @"message",
                       nil
                   ];
/* make the API call */
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/{page-id}/feed"
                         parameters:params
                         HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                  completionHandler:^(
                      FBRequestConnection *connection,
                      id result,
                      NSError *error
                  ) {
                      /* handle the result */
                  }];
```